# How do I replicate this code (Python) in Objective C++?

Tags: python, swift, opencv, objective-c++

I'm developing this Swift project that uses OpenCV's Harris Corner. Because of the different languages, I'm using Objective C++ as the intermediary language. I'm following this tutorial, however now I am having trouble replicating a line of code (Python) in Objective C++.

```
filename = 'chessboard.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

#result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
**img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]** //This is the line I don't know how to write in Objective C++
```

At the moment, I have this code, all except the last line:

```
+ (NSArray<NSArray<NSNumber *> *> *)harrisonCorners:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat mat;
    [image convertToMat: &mat];

    cv::Mat gray, corner, dst;
    if (mat.channels() > 1) {
        cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    } else {
        mat.copyTo(gray);
    }

    cv::cornerHarris(gray, corner, 2, 3, 0.04);

    //The line of code should be here

    return nil;//Return a 2D array with the corners
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably tag [python]

Comment: The top code snippet is in python not c++.

Comment: Not the answer, but definitely a typo: you have `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` in Python, but `COLOR_RGB2GRAY` in Objective C++, it's not the same.

Comment: It seems to be evaluating `dst>0.01*dst.max()` to either true or false (0 or 1) and using the result to index into `img` and set the value to `[0,0,255]`. Converting to Objective-C++ doesn't seem like It would be too hard judging that it isn't more complex than the other code you have already written. Also, It seems like you have missed the second last line in the conversion code too.

Comment: @jackw11111 Thanks for the translation of the code. I didn't include the second last step because the tutorial said it was unimportant, however I will include that line after I finish this part of the method.